# Powershell get element by classname from HTML

Tags: html, powershell

Imagine there is a webpage containing

```
<td>
  <span class="info">Containing Numbers</span>
  <span class="info">Containing *#@</span>
  <span class="info">containing characters and numbers 834</span>
  <span class="info">543</span>
</td>
```

And Powershell script should get "543" as a $value. 
So I need Powershell to get the single value with "info" class that contains ONLY numbers.

I already tried searching and I got no code working all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Check out this cmdlet that allows you to parse HTML: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Powershell-Tip-Parsing-49eb8810

Update:

Then you can get the element by ID and use a regular expression to verify the value is numerical:

```
^[\d\.]+$
```

Next, verify length is 3.

Update:

Or use this regex to verify both numerical and length of 3:

```
^\s*[0-9]{3}\s*$
```

Comment: if only I could have more info, my question is to get the page, and to have only numbers. thanks.